# UDF - different results when auto-ran than when walked through

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I have the following UDF, saved into a module of my workbook:

```
Function sumAbove2(myCell As Range)

Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim topRow As Long
topRow = myCell.Offset(0, -2).End(xlUp).Row
Dim sRng As Range, eRng As Range
Set sRng = Cells(myCell.Row, myCell.Column)
Set eRng = Cells(topRow, myCell.Column)

For Each cel In Range(sRng, eRng)
    Debug.Print cel.Address
    sumAbove2 = cel.Value + sumAbove2
Next cel

End Function
```

The idea is to automatically sum "blocks" of information.

The UDF works just fine when I walk through it with `F8`.  But, when running automatically, it can give unexpected results.  The annoying thing is that I have placed this code in a brand new workbook, threw in sample data, and it never generated incorrect results...so for that, I apologize my SO friends, I can't quite get it to reproduce. I'm relatively new to UDF, so may be missing some key point about running them (does volatility help/hurt?)

[image: Example of the wrong values being added. Note it catches the values from the cells above it.]

And when I do this, two seconds later, with a Break in the macro, I can step through with F8, it correctly adds nothing, and returns `0`.

What could be going on?  I didn't specify the sheet in the code, but I can't see why that would fix it.  Could it have to do with some other formulas on the page? There's no worksheet_change event, etc.

Edit: The workbook has a few sheets, with formulas in those sheets. But the sheet I'm running this on is all text, save the formula I'm trying to enter.  Just thought to mention in case something in formatting could be giving the odd behavior.

Comment: Are the values in the column 2 over filled with a formula?

Comment: @ScottCraner - Nope, all the info. is text (formatted as 'General'). The only formulas are my "sum above"  formulas that I'm trying to get working.

Comment: Your function needs to be volatile and when it calculates it will do so based  on the active sheet at the time. A UDF really should accept all the ranges it requires as **direct** arguments.

Comment: If you select the cell in two columns over and hit Ctrl-Up, does it go further than you would expect?

Comment: Just a thought: give it a try and fully qualify your code with `myCell.Parent.Cells(...`. In respect to `Application.Volatile` I'd like to note that this merely ensures that the formula gets re-calculated each time a value in changed on your sheet. Without that it may seem as if the formula provides incorrect results if the values (which should be summed up) are changing. Of course, for this to work you need to set your file to `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` too.

Comment: @ScottCraner - No, it goes to the row I would expect. It's very odd indeed!

Comment: Try this array formula `=SUM(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(2,IF(A1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1)="",1))):INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1))` and see how it does.  Remember CSE

Comment: @Ralph - Thanks for the suggestion. I did that, and get the same unexpected results. I also get the same errors with the code provided below. Thus, I think the problem lies *in the workbook* somehow, not the formula.  I've removed *all* other macro/UDFs from the file, and any `Worksheet Change` events, and still get this unexpected result.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I got a `#NAME` error? (placed in Col D. under the "50/50/50".  See my other comment, I'm starting to think the issue is with the workbook, not the formulas?

Comment: That error could mean that by using the comments an unprintable/invisible character was added.  Try typing it in instead.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Aha!! I tweaked it and it works now.  Where you have `A1:Index(...`, what do I change A1 to, because if I use that formula in row 10, but then want to place it in row 5, the `A1` resolves to `#REF`, since the relative reference doesn't exist. (Would you mind explaining that formula, if you can, in an answer? It looks like a great alternative to my UDF).

Comment: Make it absolute. `$A$1`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Thanks, will do.  While that's a great second solution (which I will probably use instead of my UDF), any ideas on why the UDF isn't functioning as expected? It's very odd to me. (and thanks for all your help so far, as always!)

Comment: I have no idea, as I cannot, unfortunately, reproduce the error.  It must be something with your workbook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124932/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-scott-craner).

Answer (score 1):

I would 1) simplify the code a bit (you're not using the `rng` variable for anything and you don't really need the start and end row ranges in separate variables), 2) define the data type to be returned, 3) use fully qualified references and 4) add a numeric check the following way:

```
Function sumAbove2(myCell As Range) As Double

    Dim actSht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim topRow As Long
    Dim cel As Range, searchRng As Range

    topRow = myCell.Offset(0, -2).End(xlUp).Row

    Set actSht = ActiveSheet
    With actSht
        Set searchRng = .Range(.Cells(myCell.Row, myCell.Column), .Cells(topRow, myCell.Column))
    End With

    For Each cel In searchRng
        If IsNumeric(cel.Value) Then sumAbove2 = cel.Value + sumAbove2
    Next cel

End Function
```

Seems to work flawlessly by me.

Comment: Thanks for this - I tried it, and it does the same thing for me! I run it automatically, and get incorrect results. When I step through it, I get the right results...Hmm.

Comment: This may seem far-fetched, but have you tried rebooting? On very rare occasions, I have experienced that the Excel application was malfunctioning, because something was temporarily screwed up in Windows.

Comment: Nothing is farfetched anymore! I tried restarting, same issue occurs :/

Comment: This will give incorrect results when the worksheet containing the formula is not the active sheet.

Comment: @Tim Williams. Correct, I should have used `Set sht = myCell.Worksheet` instead of `ActiveSheet`, but apart from that and with all due respect (and I do respect your extensive VBA knowledge) , I don't think your answer brings much new to the table. Fully qualified ranges is surely not the issue here after all, since the OP definitely is experienced enough to test with the correct worksheet. Something else is going on.

Comment: @BruceWayne Since the behavior of the workbook in question is erratic, my best guess is that either your workbook or your Excel application is somehow broken. 1) Test your workbook on another computer. If the problem persists: 2) As a last resort, I'd try running the code in a new workbook and then I'd recreate the old workbook step by step until I could pin-point the problem. (If the problem disappears, then the workbook was broken), This could obviously be an arduous task if the old workbook is large, but it may be your best option if everything else fails.

Comment: @Miqi180 -  I agree that it's possible the OP knows not to use ActiveSheet here, but that's not necessarily the case for everyone else who reads this: my comment is for those readers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully qualify all your ranges with the correct worksheet...

```
Function sumAbove2(myCell As Range)

    Dim sht As Worksheet '<<<
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim topRow As Long
    Dim sRng As Range, eRng As Range

    Set sht = myCell.Worksheet '<<<

    topRow = myCell.Offset(0, -2).End(xlUp).Row

    Set sRng = sht.Cells(myCell.Row, myCell.Column) '<<<
    Set eRng = sht.Cells(topRow, myCell.Column)     '<<<

    For Each cel In sht.Range(sRng, eRng) '<<<
        Debug.Print cel.Address
        sumAbove2 = cel.Value + sumAbove2
    Next cel

End Function
```

Edit: debugging UDF #VALUE errors from the worksheet is tricky - you will get more information if you debug by calling the function from a test sub:

```
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print sumAbove2(Activesheet.Range("C44"))
End sub
```

Comment: Hey Tim - thanks for this. I fully qualified them, and still get the unexpected results. I'm going to now focus on looking at the worksheet/workbook for some funky code/formatting that's causing this.  Thanks a lot though, it reinstated the importance of qualifying ranges (which I'm usually very keen to do, I just forgot here).  When I run this, as the *only* macro, it returns `#VALUE` error. When I step through it, it correctly gives the accurate sum.  So, *something* is funky in the book.